# API Яндекс Карт. Добавление информации о выбранном на карте объекте рядом с картой

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Возникла необходимость создать карту с нанесенными на неё метками объектов и выводом информации об объекте, на который кликнет пользователь, в отдельный блок рядом с картой. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как осуществить вывод информации. Или где можно об этом почитать.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, что именно непонятно. Есть документация Яндекс-карт, где описано как их использовать.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо, что откликнулись. Уже всё понятно.